# Can I replace 'perspicacious' by 'astute' here?

Tags: word-choice, difference, vocabulary

When I searched 'perspicacious' in google or bing, pictures of [Albert Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) and [Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes) turned up. So, it seems that we can use 'perspicacious' to describe them as in the following dialogs, **right?**

1. Tom: Einstein discovered the theory of relativity.

   Friend: He's such a **perspicacious** scientist.
2. Jack: Did you ever read [*A Study in Scarlet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Study_in_Scarlet)?

   Friend: Yeah, Holmes' so **perspicacious**.

**Can I replace the 'perspicacious' above by 'astute'?**

According to *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astute)*, *astute* means

> having or showing shrewdness and an ability to notice and understand things clearly: mentally sharp or clever.

One of the example uses of *astute* there is

> an astute observer.

So, it seems reasonable to describe Einstein and Holmes as *astute*. After all, they are both good observers, one of science and the other crime scene. What bothers me is, in *[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/astute)*, *astute* means

> able to understand a situation quickly and see how to **take advantage of it**.

An observer of the stock market or politics may benefit from his/her astute observation and take advantage of a situation, but how can a scientist or detective '*take advantage of it*'?

**Is it natural to use 'astute' to describe a scientist or detective?**

Comment: Einstein didn't 'discover' the theory of relativity; he originated it. It didn't have a prior existence that he uncovered.

Comment: Note that Merriam-Webster associates _astute_ with _crafty_ and _wily_. Most dictionary definitions suggest cleverness at obtaining a personal advantage from a situation.

Comment: FWIW, I have never used the word "perspicacious", I've never heard it in everyday speech, and every time I hear it in a prepared speech or see it in writing, I have to remind myself what it means.

Comment: "Holmes' so" - Holmes **is** so.

Comment: @gotube 'I've never heard it in everyday speech' - you've never been to my house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several commenters have pointed out, the word *astute* is generally associated (by dictionaries including Merriam, Wiktionary, and the OED)  with craftiness or cunning. However, I would argue that this is a somewhat traditional reading of the word; to my ear at least the word has a positive connotation (evoking accuracy, thorough incisiveness), especially when directly modifying some noun, e.g. *astute observer*, *astute analysis*, *astute investigator*.

As to if *perspicacious* is appropriate in the contexts you provide, I would join with @Michael_Harvey in saying that ***perspicacious* applies much more to a detective than to a scientist**. Good scientists are good observers of the natural world, but they are also diligent, meticulous, and various other qualities--to be sharp-eyed is not necessarily to be a good scientist. On the other hand, good detectives are sharp-eyed observers and sharp-eyed observers make good detectives, basically by definition. In the case of Einstein, the word *perspicacious* may not a particularly good choice: he didn't *observe* the theory of relativity, he *formulated* it.

In both contexts, astute *works*, but it **may not be the best choice**: a reader, if they are so inclined, might understand *astute detective* as implying that the detective is somewhat **corrupt**, or an *astute scientist* as **motivated by personal gain**, perhaps to the detriment of others. But I would like to point out that it's easy to find examples of these (or similar) phrases being used clearly absent of any such implication:

In an obituary for a dead police officer:

> He had a great way with people but he was also a very **astute policeman** and he nurtured a lot of talented officers - he mentored a lot of people and was always generous with his advice and time. [1](https://www.independent.ie/regionals/corkman/news/warm-tribute-paid-to-former-late-chief-supt-tim-callaghan-35257901.html)

In a description of a dead physician:

> Andreas Roland Grüntzig (1939-1985) was an accomplished clinician and an **astute scientist**. He was also a practical man endowed with dexterity, smartness, and common sense.[2](https://eurointervention.pcronline.com/article/his-masters-art-andreas-gruntzigs-approach-to-performing-and-teaching-coronary-angioplasty)

Finally, I'd like to add that the word *perspicacious* is quite rare. If you use it casual conversation [outside @Michael_Harvey's household (: ] it is very likely you won't be understood. I just polled three of my English major friends and none of them knew the word. Google Ngram lists it as about 20x less common tham *astute* (though the OED somehow has it in band 4, alongside *rodeo* and *overhang*)

Comment: I mentioned this to my son and he told me he said to someone at work that a colleague was perspicacious and the other person said 'Do you mean he sweats a lot'?